# Jython wsadmin: get nodeName of server

Tags: websphere, jython

In Jython WebSphere Wsadmin:

It appears that I can get to the server's names from the nodeName, however I haven't managed to find a direct way to find the nodeName of a server.

I thought about creating a map of all the nodes, but that is expensive.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the node name of the server using the Server MBean.

You can find info on the Server MBean here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.ejbfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Fcjmx_overview.html

```
objNameString = AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:type=Server,*') 
print AdminControl.getAttribute(objNameString, 'nodeName')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also get the node name using the `getNode()` method on `AdminControl`:

```
wsadmin>objn = AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:type=Server,*')

wsadmin>print AdminControl.getAttribute(objn, 'nodeName')
Node01

wsadmin>print AdminControl.getNode()
Node01
```

#### References

- [Commands for the AdminControl object using wsadmin scripting](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_admincontrol.html)